# how to append or combine 2 []array golang beego

Tags: api, go, controller, beego

I have an array like List of my data as JSON. //

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    ....
    "ClosedAt": "nine"
  },
...
]
```

I want to combine 2 arrays like and I tried to append them. -combine -append

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    ....
    "ClosedAt": "nine"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    ....
    "ClosedAt": "nine"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    ....
    "ClosedAt": "nine"
  },

...

  {
     "totalpage": 10,
  },
]
```

Controller

```
tickets, ptotal, err := models.GetAllTicket(query, fields, sortby, order, offset, limit)
if err != nil {
    i.Data["json"] = err.Error()
} else {
    i.Data["json"] = ptotal
    i.Data["json"] = tickets

}
i.ServeJSON()
```

[image: description of the JSON]

Beego(golang) API return JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import "encoding/json"

func Append(json1, json2 []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    jsonArray1 := []json.RawMessage{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(json1, &jsonArray1)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    jsonArray2 := []json.RawMessage{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(json2, &jsonArray2)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    jsonArray := append(jsonArray1, jsonArray2...)
    result, err := json.Marshal(jsonArray)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Hope it's you want

Comment: `cannot use ptotal (type int64) as type []byte in argument to Appendgo
cannot use tickets (type []interface {}) as type []byte in argument to Append`

Comment: total is int64, tickets is []interface{}

Comment: ```append(tickets, map[string]int64{"totalpage": ptotal})```