# Nested map return json array[]

Tags: json, api, go, controller, beego

How can I create a nested JSON array? Is there any other easy way to do it?

I tried this:

```
var m1 = make(map[string]interface{})
m1 = append(tickets, ptotal)                      //error is here
i.Data["json"] = m1
i.ServeJSON()
```

but it shows this error:

> cannot use append(tickets, ptotal) (type []interface {}) as type map[string]interface {} in assignment

I can do this, but it's not nested at all:

```
// some := append(tickets, map[string]int64{"totalpage": ptotal})
```

I want this JSON:

```
[
  {tickets
     name:value,
  },
],
[
  {
   totalpage: 10
  }
]
```

I want like [Playground of mine](https://play.golang.org/p/FQm274Nv4g0)

Comment: the type of m1 is map, but the result type of append is list

Comment: define m1 as []interface{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tickets []interface{}
var ptotal int64
tickets, ptotal, err := models.GetAllTicket(query, fields, sortby, order, offset, limit)
if err != nil {
    // bulabula
}
i.Data["json"] = append(tickets, map[string]int64{"totalpage": ptotal})
```

Comment: `tickets, ptotal, err := models.GetAllTicket(query, fields, sortby, order, offset, limit)` thats how i takes 3 variables, tickets is `tickets []interface{}` ptotal is `int64` error `error`

Comment: i'm not sure had understand what you mean

Comment: but I declare variable by  using  := in `tickets, ptotal, err :=` but why do i have to use var at top of it? Please explain?

Comment: Oh, it's not necessary, I just want to make it clear about the type of value

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var data = map[string]map[string]string{
    "ticket": map[string]string{},
    "totalpage": map[string]string{},
    "c": map[string]string{},
}

data["ticket"]["w"] = "vrniairvnai"
data["totalpage"]["w"] = "ten"
fmt.Println(data)

var data2 = make(map[string]interface{})
data2["data"] = data
data2["int"] = 10
fmt.Println(data2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234195/how-to-append-or-combine-2-array-golang-beego/55235252#55235252